# Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability Alert (Android)

Tags: android, android-security

I am getting the "Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability" alert in Google Play Console.

I followed official Google docs (https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9294009) to fix it but the alert is still there.

Here is the code that handles unzipping. I have even tested using a zip file that has the vulnerability described and the exception is raised as expected.

What am I missing?

```
private boolean unpackZip(File zipFile, File outputDirectory, IOnResult<Integer> progress) {
    InputStream is;
    ZipInputStream zis;
    ZipInputStream zisCount;
    try {
        int totalEntries = 0;
        int entryCount = 0;
        String filename;
        ZipEntry ze;
        is = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        zisCount = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
        while ((ze = zisCount.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            // Fixing a Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability
            // (https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9294009)
            filename = ze.getName();
            File targetFile = new File(outputDirectory, filename);
            String targetPath = targetFile.getCanonicalPath();
            if (!targetPath.startsWith(outputDirectory.getCanonicalPath())) {
                throw new SecurityException("Archive security error");
            }
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

            totalEntries++;
            zisCount.closeEntry();
        }
        zisCount.close();

        is = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            filename = ze.getName();

            // Fixing a Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability (https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9294009)
            File targetFile = new File(outputDirectory, filename);
            String targetPath = targetFile.getCanonicalPath();
            if (!targetPath.startsWith(outputDirectory.getCanonicalPath())) {
                throw new SecurityException("Archive security error");
            }

            // Need to create directories if not exists, or
            // it will generate an Exception...
            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                File fmd = new File(outputDirectory, filename);
                fmd.mkdirs();
                continue;
            }

            File outputFile = new File(outputDirectory, filename);
            for( File parentFile = outputFile.getParentFile(); !parentFile.exists(); parentFile = parentFile.getParentFile() )
            {
                parentFile.mkdir();
            }

            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            Log.d(TAG, "unzipped " + filename);
            while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }

            fout.close();
            zis.closeEntry();
            entryCount++;
        }

        zis.close();
    } catch (IOException | SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "unpackZip", e);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: did  you manage to solve it?